# How to solve inverse transform using MixMaxScaler on a single value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, inverse, minmax

I'm trying to perform the inverse of MixMaxScaler from a single value. However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=0.16019679677629.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

The code is this one:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

minmaxscaler_targets = MinMaxScaler()
minmaxscaler_targets.fit(pred)
print(minmaxscaler_targets.inverse_transform(np.array([[pred]])))
```

the value to do the inverse is pred= 0.16019679677629

Mention that the original values were already scaled (using the same function).

Updated:

If tried to reshape as mentioned with:

```
print(minmaxscaler_targets.inverse_transform(np.array([pred]).reshape(1, -1)))
```

But I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape it correctly:

```
pred = np.array([0.16])

minmaxscaler_targets = MinMaxScaler()

minmaxscaler_targets.fit(pred.reshape(-1,1))
minmaxscaler_targets.inverse_transform(pred.reshape(-1,1))
# array([[0.32]])
```

Comment: It works, thanks @seralouk, however, the inverse should be a number closer to 41

Comment: please post the input `pred` that goes in the `fit()` method

Comment: the value of 'pred.reshape(-1,1)' is [[0.15803525]]